# Xenomai to Raspberry

Tags: kernel, xenomai

I want to get Xenomai working on my Raspberry. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with compiling kernels.

I am using this documentation to get it work:
https://code.google.com/p/picnc/wiki/RPiXenomaiKernel

Actually I got some problems, with this row:

```
> make ARCH=arm O=build
> CROSS_COMPILE=/../home/pi/cross_compiler/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-
> /../home/pi/cross_compiler/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc:
> 1:
> /../home/pi/cross_compiler/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc:
> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")   Using
> /home/pi/linux-rpi-3.8.y as source for kernel   CHK    
> include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h   CHK    
> include/generated/utsrelease.h make[2]:
> 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.   CC     
> kernel/bounds.s
> /../home/pi/cross_compiler/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc:
> 1:
> /../home/pi/cross_compiler/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708hardfp-linux-gnueabi-gcc:
> Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
> /home/pi/linux-rpi-3.8.y/./Kbuild:35: recipe for target
> 'kernel/bounds.s' failed make[2]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 2
> /home/pi/linux-rpi-3.8.y/Makefile:831: recipe for target 'prepare0'
> failed make[1]: *** [prepare0] Error 2 Makefile:130: recipe for target
> 'sub-make' failed make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

I hope somebody could at least explain me what should be the problem with that.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't help you with Xenomai, but are you sure it's really needed? Very few applications require it.

Comment: I know. I'm just having a course about Xenomai and I just do not want to go to the University to validate all my assignments running as expected.

Comment: There is no remote access to your University? (that would be unusual) but yah it looks like you are mixing CROSS_COMPILE with compiling on the pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just been trying to build the kernel on my Pi following the http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation guide and got exactly the same error.

Googling around it appears that these instructions are mixed and are really targeting cross compilation, that when you are building on the Pi are causing this issue.

After setting up the config for the kernel just run make, no need to reference the build tools, Architecture or anything else.

Another account for building on the Pi is here https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/437#issuecomment-28938920